# How to prevent terminating command to send EOF to named pipes?

Tags: bash, fifo

The problem I faced is exactly this one: http://www.linuxmisc.com/4-linux/d7863c256bccbfb6.htm

> I want to be able to run a program which takes stdin, and write data 
>   to it whenever I feel like it. I can do this with fifo named pipes. e.g.:
>
> > `txtplay < named_pipe.fifo`
> >
> > `echo "Hello World" > named_pipe.fifo`
>
> However, this has the disadvantage of the first command exiting 
>   after the second has finished. What I want is the same as:
>
> > `txtplay`
>
> in effect, so I can just stick in my data whenever I like, and not worry 
>   about it seeing end-of-file. Unfortunately, I cannot simply do this, as I 
>   want the data to be sent to it to be processed through a filter before the 
>   program sees it.
>
> Why don't I just load the program each time I want to send data to 
>   it? Too slow.
>
> What I want, basically, is a way of redirecting the output of a 
>   given command to a fifo named pipe, without the end-of-file. While I'm at 
>   it, how does this EOF business work? Is there a special "EOF" command, or is 
>   it when no more data is received, or when the original program outputting 
>   the data exits?

Is there any solution to that?

Comment: echo does not send an EOF, it sends a new line. You can suppress the new line with the -n option. I guess the EOF you see is the EOF of the file you created. There is a good chance that I'm misunderstanding your issue, so this is only a comment.

Comment: The EOF is created when the `echo` is terminated, as pointed by @Luno.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run all your commands in a sub-shell (or in bash, within parenthesis), and redirect the subshell to the named pipe.

```
( 
     # some stuff
     echo "foo"
     # some other stuff
     echo "bar"
     # end of my commands
) > /home/foo/bar/named_pipe
```

And to answer the EOF question, EOF is written when the file handle closes. If you redirect from a program, you get EOF when that program (echo, in this case) terminates.  By encapsulating multiple commands in parenthesis, you only get one EOF when the close parenthesis is reached.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have thought about this this morning, but that time I couldn't apply it to my use case. Apparently after some more thoughts, it's actually possible. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

If you keep a handle open to the pipe, then it won't be closed by each echo command.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
fifo_with_exec() {
    echo "fifo_with_exec"

    readonly TMP_PIPE=$(mktemp -u)
    mkfifo -m 600 ${TMP_PIPE}
    echo "pipe created:  ${TMP_PIPE}"

    # Here is the important bit
    exec 9<> ${TMP_PIPE}

    zenity --progress --no-cancel < ${TMP_PIPE} &
    zenity_pid=$!
    echo "zenity_pid: ${zenity_pid}"

    echo "0" > ${TMP_PIPE}
    echo "#Run command A" > ${TMP_PIPE}
    echo "output of command A"
    sleep 2
    echo "40"  > ${TMP_PIPE}

    echo "#Run command B" > ${TMP_PIPE}
    echo "output of command B"
    sleep 2
    echo "80" > ${TMP_PIPE}

    echo "#Run command C" > ${TMP_PIPE}
    echo "output of command C"
    sleep 0.5
    echo "100" > ${TMP_PIPE}
}
fifo_with_exec
```

If you remove that exec statement you will notice that the function hangs on the second echo, as Zenity stops when it sees EOF from the first echo.