# nc and named pipes for port forwarding

Tags: port-forwarding, netcat, named-pipe

I have my environment setup to listen to jetty on port 8888. However, for a limited time, I will have to also listen on 8889.

I though of using named pipes and nc for that:

```
mkfifo pipe1
/bin/nc -l 8889 0<pipe1 | /bin/nc localhost 8888 1>pipe1
```

I noticed that the port forwarding will only work for a certain amount of time, returning the prompt after.

Why is it only working for a certain amount of time?

Is there a better port forwarding mechanism I could use? All of this runs on my local machine, between the ports 8888 and 8889.

This is on a Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: your command says mkinfo instead of mkfifo

Answer (score 0):

An EOF may be killing it. The following may help:

In [netcat - keep listening for connection in Debian](https://superuser.com/questions/1008348/netcat-keep-listening-for-connection-in-debian) the asker points out:

`"There's -q -1 option to listen forever after EOF appears on stdin".`

If you want to try to avoid the EOF try [How to prevent terminating command to send EOF to named pipes?](https://superuser.com/questions/766414/how-to-prevent-terminating-command-to-send-eof-to-named-pipes)