# netcat - keep listening for connection in Debian

Tags: linux, networking, debian, netcat

There's `-k` option in OS X (BSD) version of netcat to keep listening after current connection is completed. However in Debian (GNU?) version this option is missing.

There's `-q -1` option to listen forever after EOF appears on stdin but this doesn't do the trick and connections close anyway.

Is there any way to force Debian's netcat to keep listening indefinitely?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Debian's implementation of Netcat does have the `-k` option. However, it's not documented in the manual because it doesn't work in a reliable manner, for some unknown reason.

Luckily, there's `ncat`, which is yet another implementation of Netcat and is part of the `nmap` package. This one has a working `-k`. You can get it by installing `nmap`. `ncat`'s options and usage are more or less similar to other implementations of Netcat, so your knowledge of other implementations should transfer very well to `ncat`.

Comment: Thank you! Thanks to you I found best version of netcat ever.

Comment: [openbsd-netcat](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/netcat-openbsd) appears to have the `-k` option as well

Comment: Package is `netcat-openbsd`, not `openbsd-netcat` for those who might not click @AndrewSavinykh link

Comment: `ncat` worked for me in macos

Comment: `ncat`, UDP and `-k` don't work together: `ncat -u -l -k 1900` results in `Ncat: UDP mode does not support the -k or --keep-open options, except with --exec or --sh-exec. QUITTING.`

Comment: @Robin Thoni it is called `openbsd-netcat` on arch Linux

Comment: At least in recent versions of Debian, ncat is the package [ncat](https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/ncat); installing nmap does not install ncat.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem if netcat gets a rst or fin packet, I think.

You could simply call netcat again as soon as it closes using a bash loop.

```
while true; do nc -lv <listeningport> ; done
```

Comment: Welcome on the SU! Please explain, what your code is doing and how does it work.

Comment: This is different from `ncat` or opensbd-ncat  `-k` option, which will actually allow multiple clients to connect at the same time; your solution will only allow one after the other

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica it is doing a loop that starts a new netcat command when the previous one has returned. While true for infinite loop.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. After the message is sent, netcat just hangs until I press Enter. Maybe because I'm listening on UDP? Adding `-w0` to the netcat command fixes it, e.g. `while true; do nc -luv 5140 -w0; done`

Answer (score 0):

dind't work for me, also using UDP listener. The -w0 solved the problem.
while true; do nc -luv 5140 -w0; done

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).