# How to store data from different netcat connections in separate files?

Tags: bash, pipe, xargs, netcat, tee

I need a server that should receive data streams, store them in files and send further. Each connection should create a file with corresponding timestamp in file name, then write to it.

My solution:

```
nc -l -k -p 4000 | date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H_%M_%S" | xargs -I {} tee file_{}.dat | nc 192.168.0.3 4001
```

It worked before decision about timestamps and separate files was made, but now I'm stuck on creation of files. netcat complains: getaddrinfo: name or service not known

Comment: You're outputing your first command (`nc`) to a file named `date`.

Please, make your example more clear (hopefully a single script or "two terminal windows").

Comment: Indeed, my mistake. Corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. EOF is not piped to the next command when a connection ends. See [this other answer](https://superuser.com/a/766507/384482)